# MKAnnotationView image changing issue

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I've got an MKMapView loaded with plenty of custom annotation (800 circa).

When I drag on the map and I return to an annotation, it's image has changed with another one. For me it's seems like a cache issue.

#### Pin before dragging

[image: Before dragging]

#### Pin after dragging

[image: After dragging]

#### SuperClass header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property NSString * pinImageName;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString *)title pinImageName:(NSString *)pinImageName;

- (MKAnnotationView *)getAnnotationView;
@end
```

#### SubClass (the one that creates the issue) header

```
#import "MapAnnotation.h"
#import "Company.h"

@interface CompanyAnnotation : MapAnnotation

@property Company *company;
@property UIImage *pinImage;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString *)title pinImage:(UIImage *)pinImage;
- (MKAnnotationView *)getAnnotationView;

@end
```

#### viewForAnnotation delegate method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation {
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation){
        return nil;
    }

    MapAnnotation *location = [MapAnnotation new];
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [MKAnnotationView new];

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CompanyAnnotation class]]) {
        location = (CompanyAnnotation *)annotation;
        annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"companyAnnotation"];
    }

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [location getAnnotationView];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return annotationView;
}
```

#### getAnnotationView method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)getAnnotationView {
    MKAnnotationView * annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:self reuseIdentifier:@"companyAnnotation"];
    [annotationView setEnabled:YES];
    [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];
    [annotationView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [annotationView setImage:self.pinImage];
    [annotationView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 44)];
    [annotationView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]];

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code for the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method and the `getAnnotationView` methods?  Sounds like the dequeue is not being handled properly ("cache" issue as you say).

Comment: Your question does not mention the main part of implementation i.e. annotation creation. Please be descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dequeue is not being handled properly in `viewForAnnotation` because when `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` returns a previously-used view (when `annotationView` is not `nil`), the code is only updating that view's `annotation` property:

```
if (annotationView == nil) {
    annotationView = [location getAnnotationView];
} else {
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
}
```

But the annotation view's `image` is not updated -- in a dequeued view, the `image` will be set to the one associated with the annotation the view was *originally* created for (when `getAnnotationView` was called).

So now the view appears at the new annotation's coordinates but the image is still from the previous annotation the view was used for.

There are various ways to fix this such as creating a proper subclass of `MKAnnotationView` that monitors changes to its `annotation` property and automatically updates all other properties associated with an annotation.

With the existing code, a simple way to fix it is to separate out the annotation-specific property changes into a separate method that can be called both when the view is created and when its `annotation` property is updated.

For example, in `CompanyAnnotation`, create a method like this:

```
-(void)configureView:(MKAnnotationView *)av
{
    av.image = self.pinImage;
}
```

Then change `getAnnotationView` to:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)getAnnotationView {
    MKAnnotationView * annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:self reuseIdentifier:@"companyAnnotation"];

    //set properties here that are not specific to an annotation...
    [annotationView setEnabled:YES];
    [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];
    [annotationView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    //[annotationView setImage:self.pinImage];
    [annotationView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 44)];
    [annotationView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]];

    //set properties that are specific to an annotation...
    [self configureView:annotationView];

    return annotationView;
}
```

Finally in `viewForAnnotation`:

```
if (annotationView == nil) {
    annotationView = [location getAnnotationView];
} else {
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CompanyAnnotation class]]) {
        //update image, etc...
        [annotation configureView:annotationView];
    }
}
```

Note that `MapAnnotation` will have the same issue with the `pinImageName` property.