# MKAnnotationView wrong image display

Tags: xamarin.ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have four types of custom annotation. I subclass PointAnnotation and which will define which enum type of the annotation is. Custom type is annotations that I get from the backend and added them dynamically. Adding the annotation is fine. But when I move map the image of annotation change and I also notice it changed the type of annotation.

**At First when I got all annotations from back end it looks like this>**
[image]

**And then I add one custom annotation** 
[image]

and When I zoom out the map annotation changes to the recent annotation image changes to the recent one.
[image]

My code is:

```
override public MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
         string resuseId = "";

         MKAnnotationView annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(resuseId);

        if (ThisIsTheCurrentLocation(mapView, annotation))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (annotationView == null)
        {

            if (annotation is CustomAnnotation)
            {
                switch (CustomAnnotation.MarkerType)
                {
                    case MyMarkerType.Note:
                        annotationView = new MKAnnotationView(annotation, resuseId = "Note");
                        annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Message");
                        annotationView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
                       // CGPointMake(0, -imageHeight / 2).
                        annotationView.CanShowCallout = false;
                        break;
                    case MyMarkerType.Photo:
                        annotationView = new MKAnnotationView(annotation, resuseId = "Photo");
                        annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Photo");
                        annotationView.CanShowCallout = false;
                        break;
                    case MyMarkerType.Story:
                        annotationView = new MKAnnotationView(annotation, resuseId = "Story");
                        annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Story");
                        annotationView.CanShowCallout = false;
                        break;
                    case MyMarkerType.Custom:
                        annotationView = new MKAnnotationView(annotation, resuseId = "Custom");
                        NSData data = NSData.FromArray(CustomAnnotation.WayPoint.Image);
                        UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
                        // UIImage finalImage = image.MaxResizeImage(21f, 20f);
                        annotationView.Image = image;
                        annotationView.CanShowCallout = false;
                        break;

                    default:
                        annotationView.Annotation = annotation;
                        break;
                }
            }

            else  //not custom view
            {
                annotationView = new MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation, "cluster");
            }

        }

        else
        {
            annotationView.Annotation = annotation;

        }

         annotationView.CanShowCallout = false;
        return annotationView;

    }
```

I had a look to this answer
[MKAnnotationView image changing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122625/mkannotationview-image-changing-issue)
 But couldn't figure out in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it incorrectly when reuse the annotationView , we should use different `resuseId` to classify `custom view` and `default view`.

#### Code

```
override public MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

        if (ThisIsTheCurrentLocation(mapView, annotation))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (annotation is CustomAnnotation) //custom view
        {
            annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation("CustomID");

            if (annotationView == null)
            {
                annotationView = new MKAnnotationView(annotation, resuseId = "CustomID");
            }

            switch (CustomAnnotation.MarkerType)
            {
                case MyMarkerType.Note:

                    annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Message");
                    annotationView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
                    break;
                case MyMarkerType.Photo:
                    annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Photo");
                    break;
                case MyMarkerType.Story:
                    annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Story");
                    break;
                case MyMarkerType.Custom:
                    NSData data = NSData.FromArray(CustomAnnotation.WayPoint.Image);
                    UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
                    // UIImage finalImage = image.MaxResizeImage(21f, 20f);
                    annotationView.Image = image;
                    break;
                default:
                    annotationView.Annotation = annotation;
                    break;
            }

            annotationView.Annotation = annotation;
        }
    
        else  //not custom view
        {
            annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation("DefaultID");

            if(annotationView == null)
            {
                annotationView = new MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation, "DefaultID");
            }

            annotationView.Annotation = annotation;   
        }

        annotationView.CanShowCallout = false;
        return annotationView;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's much better now but I am still getting one weird bug. First zoom in and zoom out it doesn't change the view now. When I try to add custom annotation later (annotationView== null) statement is false so it goes to else statement. In real I wanted to add new annotation and it supposed to be true. Do you have any clue to solve that? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KopilaPanth refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703347/adding-a-custom-annotation-to-a-mkmapview), check my update code .

Comment: Now works like a charm. Thank you, @Cole Xia. Appreciate.

Comment: No problem ..:)